# Laravel queue worker can't process jobs # Error log local.ERROR: Class does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel 5.6 jobs queue to avoid email sending delay in my project and its , not working 
.

**My log file contains below error**

> [2020-06-14 12:46:03] local.ERROR: Class  does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class  does not exist at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:767)
>   [stacktrace]
>
> #0 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(767): ReflectionClass->__construct('')
>
> #1 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(646): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(NULL)
>
> #2 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(601): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve(NULL, Array)
>
> #3 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container->make(NULL, Array)
>
> #4 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(184): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make(NULL)
>
> #5 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(83): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->resolve(NULL)
>
> #6 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(326): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
>
> #7 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(276): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> #8 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(118): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> #9 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> #10 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
>
> #11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
>
> #12 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> #13 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
>
> #14 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
>
> #15 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
>
> #16 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(179): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
>
> #17 /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
>
> #18 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(166): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
>
> #19 /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1000): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> #20 /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(271): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> #21 /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(147): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> #22 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(89): 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> #23 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> #24 /var/www/html/project/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> #25 {main}

Comment: This post is hard to read and understand

Comment: Email Job not working that is  the actual issue .. the long code is error log .. i thought its useful to somebody

Comment: the error is good but it doesn't let us see what class is actually trying to be resolved, perhaps the queue job itself has bad data in the payload, but couldn't say without more information

Comment: bad data payload means? can you clarify this? (All other configuration are fine like env  mail etc because same configuration working in another project )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class  does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class  does not exist at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:767)
[stacktrace]

**Reflection Exception** is occurred due to version conflict of php and laravel see  [link](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/16/4/0/reflection)  for more about the reflection exception.

**i have changed my php version and run composer update . now it is working**